# Where can I use Skull of the Corrupted Shaman?

Tags: core-keeper

I've got a Crystal Skull Shard during the playthrough.

[image: crystal skull shard]

This requires you to correct ten of those, and once you have ten it will fuses into Skull of the Corrupted Shaman once used.

[image: skull of the corrupted shaman]

So, it says that, *It urges you to place it on the throne room sigil*.

My question is, where is it located? Though I searched inside/outside the barrier, I did not find a throne or anything of the sort. Google didn't provide good results, sadly.

Is it still unimplemented? If not, where should I look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's where you use it. It's a throne room of some kind that can be found in the Old Ruins biome. You don't actually place the skull on the throne though. You actually put it on the Skull Symbol on the ground where you can see my player standing. Hope this helps!
[image: Here's the screenshot.]

Comment: Figured so, since it says "~place it on the throne room sigil". Anyway, thanks for the information! I'll take a look at old ruins. One question: Should I prepare for the boss fight or something like that? that room sure looks like boss area or something.

Comment: Nevermind; I found the place and placed my Skull of the Corrupted Shaman. It summoned a boss called Malugaz the Corrupted, he then proceeded to vaporize me (!). Stronger than any boss I've ever fought, lol.